# Running the PyQGIS script without opening the project in the GUI

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a successful Python code that runs in the QGIS Python Console when a project is open to calculate the shortest path between hundreds of points. I now want to run the code across lots of projects without actually opening them in the GUI, but still using the QGIS Python Console.

My code runs but it fails to calculate the shortest path. Do I need to amend or change the code to ensure it runs without opening the project in the GUI?

Below are some key parts of the code.

```
  import os
  import shutil
  import Mergin.mergin as mergin
  from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsProcessingException, QgsField, 
  QgsSpatialIndex
  from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
  import processing
  from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  Processing.initialize()

    def calculate_shortest_paths():
        layer = node_layer
        layer.startEditing()

        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"apollo_vertex_id" > 0 AND "parent_fnc_chain" > 0 AND ("apollo_ticp_mat_type" IN (\'materials_dn\', \'materials_zn\', \'materials_an\'))')
        crs = layer.crs().authid()

        vertex_id_to_geometry = {feature.attribute('apollo_vertex_id'): feature.geometry() for feature in layer.getFeatures()}

        def get_geom_by_vertex_id(vertex_id):
            return vertex_id_to_geometry.get(vertex_id, None)

        def calculate_shortest_path_length(start_point_crs, end_point_crs):
            try:
                processing.core.Processing.Processing.initialize()
                result = processing.run("native:shortestpathpointtopoint", {
                 'INPUT': route_layer,
                 'STRATEGY': 0,  # Shortest path
                 'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',  # Empty string, assuming no direction field in your dataset
                 'VALUE_FORWARD': '',  # Empty string, assuming no specific value for forward direction
                 'VALUE_BACKWARD': '',  # Empty string, assuming no specific value for backward direction
                 'VALUE_BOTH': '',  # Empty string, assuming no specific value for both directions
                 'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,  # Both directions (0: Forward direction, 1: Backward direction, 2: Both directions)
                 'SPEED_FIELD': '',  # Empty string, assuming no speed field in your dataset
                 'DEFAULT_SPEED': 50,  # Default speed in km/h
                 'TOLERANCE': 10,
                 'START_POINT': start_point_crs,
                 'END_POINT': end_point_crs,
                 'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
                })
            except QgsProcessingException:
                return None

            shortest_path_layer = result.get('OUTPUT')
            if not shortest_path_layer:
                return None

            return sum([feature.geometry().length() for feature in shortest_path_layer.getFeatures()])

        for feature in layer.getFeatures(request):
            startnode = feature.attribute('apollo_vertex_id')
            endnode = feature.attribute('parent_fnc_chain')
            Sgeom = get_geom_by_vertex_id(startnode)
            Egeom = get_geom_by_vertex_id(endnode)

            if not (Sgeom and Egeom):
                print(f'{startnode} to {endnode} Length = Error!')
                continue

            start_point = Sgeom.asPoint()
            end_point = Egeom.asPoint()
            start_point_crs = f'{start_point.x()},{start_point.y()} [{crs}]'
            end_point_crs = f'{end_point.x()},{end_point.y()} [{crs}]'
            lengthresult = calculate_shortest_path_length(start_point_crs, end_point_crs)

            if lengthresult is None:
                print(f'{startnode} to {endnode} Length = No Path Exists!')
                continue

            field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName('node_connection_length')
            feature[field_index] = lengthresult
            layer.updateFeature(feature)
            print(f'{startnode} to {endnode} Length = {lengthresult}')

        layer.commitChanges()
        print("Shortest Path Scrape Completed!")

    calculate_shortest_paths()
```

Comment: What is `node_layer`?

Comment: How exactly does it fail?

Comment: Got it sorted all, I didn’t provide the full code to hide some info etc. turns out I needed to input the locations as strings instead of CRS, seen on another post that using processing tools with standalone scripts can be Funny and you need try different input methods